# custom hashing algorithm to generate unique id using some alphanumeric string

Tags: java, algorithm, hash, hashcode

I will need to generate one unique id with all digits, using some hashing algorithm. Currently I am having some base64 encoded id like "BTS_MDEyMzQ1Njc4OQ==_1". I wanted to generate the unique-id using this string.
I have used the below algorithm to generate, however it does not look very promising. There are many chances that the duplicate id number can be generated as unique-id using this algorithm.
Ref: https://opendsa-server.cs.vt.edu/ODSA/Books/CS3/html/HashFuncExamp.html

```
static int hashing(String x) {
    char ch[];
    ch = x.toCharArray();
    int xlength = x.length();

    int i, sum;
    for (sum=0, i=0; i < x.length(); i++) {
        sum += ch[i];
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Can someone please suggest if there is easy simple solution available.

Comment: What about first decode the base64 string to get the data bits. If you are lucky there are less or equal data bits than the bits you can afford for your ID (You never mentioned how many bits your unique id should have).

Comment: Actually, My Base64 string is combination of BTS_+some_ID+_seq-no. Hence I cannot use the decoded form of it.  Also, My requirement of unique id length is 10 digit fixed.

Comment: What is the length of the hash ? What is the range of possible characters ?

Comment: Looks like in your example the Base64 part is an 10 digit number (represented as a string) (MDEyMzQ1Njc4OQ==_1 -> "0123456789") Is it just a test example or is it always a string representation of a 10 digit base 10 number?

Comment: I want to store hash function result in an integer variable. Length of hash value  should be 10. There should not be any character in hash value. However in input, we have alphanumeric string with special characters.

Comment: @MrSmith42, Yes it is an example. That number can be any 8-10 digit number in my decoded string.

Comment: Did you consider `"BTS_MDEyMzQ1Njc4OQ==_1".hashCode()` ?

Comment: @c0der, Yes. However using `hashCode()` method, the length varies from 7 to 11 digit number based on the input decoded string.

Comment: Did you consider `("BTS_MDEyMzQ1Njc4OQ==_1".hashCode() ) % 10000000000`  ? How bad collisions are should still be checked.